# Styling appended elements

Tags: jquery

I'm building some of a webpage using `.append()` to add elements to another generated parent element. I want to style the added elements, but none of the styles given to them using `.css()` are applied, possibly due to the fact these elements haven't been added to the page yet?

Here's my code:

```
var stickyHeader = $("<div></div>");

$(".stickyHeader").find("th").each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset().left;
    var objWidth = $(this).width();

    stickyHeader.append("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>").css({width: objWidth, top: 0, left: offset, position: 'fixed'});
});

$("body").append("<div class=\"stickyHeader\">" + stickyHeader.html() + "</div>");
```

Do I need another `.each()` to loop through the `span`s once theyre added to `body`, or is there a nicer, cleaner solution?

I forgot to mention that each `span` is given a width from another element on the page, so this can't be done solely with CSS and classes.

Comment: I see no `css()` usage in your posted code.

Comment: Well that's just proven I'm an idiot. Thanks for the heads up. I've added my `css()` to the question.

Comment: You are selecting the `stickyHeader's` html which is the html of `stickyHeader` wrapped in a `<span>` tag? Isn't that redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying the css to the container div and not the appended elements, which I guess is what you are after. Try:

```
var span = $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
             .css({width: objWidth, 
                   top: 0, 
                   left: offset, 
                   position: 'fixed'});
stickyHeader.append(span);
```

Comment: This works really well. Thank you for the simple solution and good answer.

Answer (score 3):

.append forces a redraw. That consumes resources and slows down your UI. It's best to build up your HTML in an object or string and insert it into the DOM all at once.

Let CSS do the heavy-lifting, preferably from an external stylesheet. Inline styles must be parsed, which slows things down as well.

Comment: What if I'm appending it to a jQuery object given to a variable?

Comment: +1 for "It's best to build up your HTML in an object or string and insert it into the DOM all at once."

Comment: Yes, assign it to a variable, then append it in one go at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The nice, clean solution to adding styles to new elements is to make sure they have the correct classes/ids and that you've got a well-written CSS stylesheet.

Comment: @zzzz: If you take a little longer to read my code, you'll see that some styles are defined using the properties from other elements.

Comment: @JamWaffles, i responded before you'd updated your code. I was making the assumption that you were using a `css` call instead using stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

If the class you are attaching to the elements is already defined and styled in your css file then the element will automatically take on those styles.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, use css file ^^, look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHkQW/5/)

Comment: Another solution, try looking at my code to see why this won't work.

Comment: Exact ... sorry for the precipitated response